# SQL Server Integration Service Error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have the next query in a SSIS task

```
UPDATE Table_A
SET 
   Table_A.column1 = Table_B.column1,
   Table_A.column2 = Table_B.column2, 
   Table_A.column3 = Table_B.column3, 
   Table_A.column4 = Table_B.column4, 
   Table_A.column5 = Table_B.column5 
FROM 
   Table_A 
INNER JOIN 
   Table_B ON (Table_A.column6 = Table_B.column6) 
            AND (Table_A.column7 = Table_B.column7) 
            AND (Table_A.column8 = Table_B.column8)
```

But when I execute the program, I get this error:

> Execute SQL Task Error: Executing the query "UPDATE Tabla_A
>   SET 
>   Tabla_A..." failed with the following error: "The statement has been terminated.". 
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly.

Is there something wrong with the query?. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Comment: In the query posted you've mispelt `UPDATE Tabla_A`, bu tI guess that's not it. Paste it into SSMS and run it to get a useful error.

Comment: Also... what's your resultset set to in the task - none?

Comment: I second @Nick.McDermaid , looks like you mispelt `Tabla_A` in your update statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have fixed the problem, it was necessary to match the length of the columns between the two tables